# How to send an exe file through a json request

Tags: java, html, json, request

I'm sending an html request that will be used to send an email.
I would like to send an exe file in the json that will be attached to the email as well.
is it possible to do that?

```
URL url = new URL (url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        String jsonInputString = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"emailaddress\":\"user@mail.com\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"emailSubject\": \"hello\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"emailBody\": \"Hello from Microsoft Flow triggered by java\"\r\n" + 
                "}";
        System.out.println(jsonInputString);
        try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
        }
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String responseLine = null;
                    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(responseLine.trim());
                    }
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
```

this html request serves as a trigger for a flow in power automate

Comment: Base64-encode it?

Comment: I tried but then the file gets corrupted :(

Comment: In that case, it's either being encoded wrongly or decoded wrongly